# Typescript sorting Type by required first

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, jsx, eslint

I am looking for a plugin or ESLint rule that makes the case that sorting of types will be done by assuming required first while not required below.

Example before:

```
type TExampleSorting = {
  title?: string;
  value?: number;
  text: string;
}
```

Example after:

```
type TExampleSorting = {
  text: string; <--- required first
  title?: string;
  value?: number;
};
```

How can I make it so that such sorting takes place after the TSX file is saved?

Is there any reasonable solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys) allows you to sort alphabetically and required.

You can find how to configure it by clicking the two links at the bottom of the plugin's [GitHub page](https://github.com/infctr/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys) - [typescript-sort-keys/interface](https://github.com/infctr/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys/blob/master/docs/rules/interface.md) and [typescript-sort-keys/string-enum](https://github.com/infctr/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys/blob/master/docs/rules/string-enum.md)

---

If you use VSCode, you can set it to fix on save.

Create a `.vscode` folder in your root and create a `settings.json` file with the following.

```json
{
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
 },
 "eslint.validate": ["javascript"]
}
```

[Digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/workflow-auto-eslinting) has a detailed post on how to fix on save.